# How can I set the arguments which has been set to variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, arguments

I set the function to variables by using t() method. Now that c is a function right now, I can use the arguments having been passed to this function. But I can not do that. My main goal is that to set the data to i and use the data inside the code.

```
var i = 5;
var c;
var t = function(x) {
  this.c = x;
};
t(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
c.arguments[0] = i;
c();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use apply to pass arguments

```
   var i = 5;
   var c;
   var t = function(x) {
       this.c = x;
   }
   t(function(data) {
       console.log(data)
   });
   c.apply(this, [i]); // 5
```

or you can use bind like this

```
var i = 5;
   var c;
   var t = function(x){
   this.c=x;
   }
   t(function(data){
    console.log(data)});
   var x = c.bind(this, i)
   x(); // 5
```

Comment: Can you write 5 to console by using "data" argument?

Comment: what do you mean?
x(); // 5 and c.apply(this, [i]); // 5 
both writing giving 5 by console.log(data)

Comment: I meant that, your first option is passed to i to c, and in the second option you created new x variable to achieve that. Can you bind the c to i by using argument[] ? otherwise I will use your first option.